# How to drag color chooser on other colors to get that color?

Tags: android-studio, colors

I want to pick colors via color picker in colors of android studio. I tried to move that color chooser to pick up colors but its not moving.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In latest stable version,this issue already fixed.